# binary .dat file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can access the binary data file(.DAT). i am using geonames API. can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you add anymore details? Such as programming platform/language, file format of the dat file, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the binary flat file format used by MaxMinds GeoLocation database, they offer some handy utility classes in C# and Java to access it.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/api

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C# (from the tag), you can use [`BinaryReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) to read binary data. See [How to read and write to a binary file](http://www.tanguay.info/web/codeExample.php?id=817):

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\settings.bin", FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

long number = reader.ReadInt64();
byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(3);
string s = reader.ReadString();

reader.Close();
fs.Close();

Console.WriteLine(number);
foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
    Console.Write("[{0}]", b);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```